# Physical relation between adiabatic constant $\gamma$ and polytropic index $n$

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics, stars, neutron-stars

I am study about stellar model of stars by using polytropic equation of state $$P=k\rho ^{\gamma}$$ or $$P=k\rho ^{1+1/n }.$$
I studied that different values of polytropic index $n$ describes different physical interpretation of stars in stellar configurations. I want to  know is there any physical acceptable posiblibity where $$\gamma = n$$ and what may be the physical description of the compact object in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let us suppose $n\neq 0$. If $\gamma = n$, then by direct substitution we have

$$ n = 1 + \frac{1}{n}\ ,$$

i.e.

$$ n^{2} - n - 1 = 0\ ,$$

a second-order equation with two roots,

$$ n_{1} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\ ,$$
$$ n_{2} = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}\ .$$

The first scenario, with $n_{1} > 0$ is, from a physical point of view, slightly more familiar. To understand its impact, let us here recall three famous polytropic indices:

1. The ideal gas (in the limit $T\neq 0$ and $T\equiv$ constant): $\gamma_{\text{Id}} = 1$.
2. Relativistic fermions: $\gamma_{\text{RF}} = 4/3\ \approx \text{1.333}$,
3. Non-relativistic fermions: $\gamma_{\text{NRF}} = 5/3\ \approx \text{1.666}$.

Since $\sqrt{5}\approx 2.23606$, we have $\gamma_{1} = n_{1}\approx 1.618$ (a number also called $\textit{the golden ratio}$). Clearly,

$$\gamma_{1} > \gamma_{\text{Id}}\ \ \text{and}\ \ \gamma_{1} > \gamma_{\text{RF}}\ ,$$
and
$$\gamma_{1} < \gamma_{\text{NRF}}\ .$$

Now, since $\gamma_{\text{NRF}} - \gamma_{1}\ \approx 0.05$ and $\gamma_{1} - \gamma_{\text{RF}}\ \approx 0.28$, $\textbf{we might infer the resulting polytrope behaves almost like a non-relativistic fermionic gas.}$ Let us say a little bit more about these polytropes by analyzing the speed of sound,
$$c_{\text{sound}} = \sqrt{\frac{dP}{d\rho}}\ .$$

Direct differentiation leads to

$$c_{\text{sound}}\propto \rho^{(\gamma - 1)/2}\ ,$$

and the replacement of our values into this proportionality relation gives $c_{\text{sound}}^{(\gamma_{1})}\propto \rho^{\text{0.309}}$ and $c_{\text{sound}}^{(\gamma_{\text{NRF}})}\propto \rho^{\text{0.333}}$. Therefore, at a fixed density (recall $\rho\gg 1$ in compact objects) we see sound propagates faster in a non-relativistic fermionic gas than in this fictitious medium. Similarly, the sound travels faster here than in an ideal gas. It must be noted this conclusion might be altered by the actual values of the front constant $K$, which in principle also depends on the selected value for $\gamma$.

To understand why the second scenario is not physical, within the context of stellar structure, let us formalize the following well-known fact: if the pressure of a system is increased, the volume decreases. Conversely, when the pressure decreases a system expands, i.e. the volume increases. Thus, $\textit{physical}$ pressures must satisfy

$$ \frac{dP}{dV} < 0\ .$$

How do we relate this with density? Under the assumption that variations of mass are unimportant, from $\rho = M/V$ we get $d\rho/dV = -1/V^{2}$. Together with the previous inequality we obtain

$$ -\rho^{2}\frac{dP}{d\rho} < 0\ ,$$

or, considering $-\rho^{2} < 0 $,

$$ \frac{dP}{d\rho} > 0\ .$$

Now, for $\textit{any}$ polytrope, we have

$$\frac{dP}{d\rho} = \gamma\frac{P}{\rho}\ .$$

Therefore, we see any $\textit{physical}$ polytrope, due to the non-negative character of $P$ and $\rho$, $\textbf{must satisfy}$ $\gamma >0$. Since $\gamma_{2} = n_{2} < 0$, we must regard this solution as $\textit{unphysical}$ from the point of view of standard stellar structure.

As a comment aside, let us mention that, outside the stellar context, we have the $\textit{dark energy}$ which is usually said to be described by $P_{\text{dark-energy}} = -\rho c^{2}$, i.e. $\textit{pressure is inherently negative}$ and does not satisfy the $dP/d\rho > 0$ constriction. Since we are dealing with compact objects only, further comment on this is definitely beyond the scope of this answer.